# Returning Proper Image from Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a collection view that shows several images. However when I tap one of the cells it's not populating the correct image.

This is my collection of images:

```
let stickers: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "cow")!,
    UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
    UIImage(named: "pig")!,
]
```

I set a default image:

```
var activeSticker = UIImage(named: "cow")
```

This function sets up the collection view and displays all of the images from above as individual cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.stickerImage.image = stickers[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    let addSticker = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    addSticker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addStickerTapped), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    activeSticker = cell.stickerImage.image
    cell.addSubview(addSticker)
    return cell
}
```

This function currently adds images to the view, but it's not the cell tapped, I'm not sure how it is setting the value.

```
@IBAction func addStickerTapped() -> Void {
    print("Hello Sticker Button")
    let image = activeSticker 
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 200)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    //Imageview on Top of View
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
    selectedImageView = imageView
}
```

Comment: Why haven't you added button in the xib itself?

Comment: You should create a custom cell class with a button and just update the image of the button for every cell. Also you can override prepareForUse() function to reset the image to default(i.e "cow") for fallback. For action listing in the controller you can use protocol delegates or closures.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move all the code of `CollectionViewCell's` layout from `cellForItemAt` to `awakeFromNib()`.

Next, create the `addSticker` `button` in the `CollectionViewCell's` `xib` itself instead of adding it everytime in `cellForItemAt`.

Also, use **`closure`** to handle the *tap event* on `addSticker` button.

So, the `CollectionViewCell` looks like,

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var stickerImage: UIImageView!
    var handler: (()->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    }

    @IBAction func onTapAddStickerButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.handler?()
    }
}
```

Now, in `cellForItemAt` create the instance of `CollectionViewCell` and set the `handler` that will be called after tapping `addSticker` button, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    let sticker = stickers[indexPath.item]
    cell.stickerImage.image = sticker
    cell.handler = {
        self.activeSticker = sticker
        //add the code after tapping the addSticker here...
    }
    return cell
}
```

I'm a bit confused with what you're trying to do in `addStickerTapped()` method. Kindly clarify more for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try to figure this out as I'm very new and will need to learn more about what a xib is. Here is a broader view of what I'm trying to accomplish:

The app has a background of a farm. The collection view has all the different animals. When you tab a item I would like the animal to appear in the farm and be moved around.

what I've accomplished so far sort of works... it does add an animal, and I can move it, but I can't get the correct animal to display.